# Convergence of composition of sequence of functions on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, function-and-relation-composition, sequence-of-function

Let $\lbrace f_n\rbrace$ and $\lbrace g_n\rbrace $ be two sequences of real-valued continuous functions on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that they converge pointwise to $f$ and $g$ respectively, where $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Then what can we say about the composite function $f_n \circ g_n$. Can we say that it will converge to $f\circ g$.

A similar question is asked here [Convergence of composition of functions sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678233/convergence-of-composition-of-functions-sequences). But here the continuity of functions $f$ and $g$ was not given. Please at least give me some hint to solve this.

Comment: Please see if my revised answer is OK.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, Thanku sir for your continuous support, I have a modification in the question that if the domain of the sequence of functions $\lbrace f_n \rbrace$ and $ \lbrace g_n \rbrace $ is compact then what we can say about the convergence  of the composition $f_n \circ g_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=nx$  for $0 \leq x \leq 1/n$, $2-nx$  for $ 1/n \leq x \leq 2/n$ and $0$ for $x >2/n$. $g_n(x)=\frac 1 n$. Let $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ and $g(x)=0$ for all $x$. Then $f_n(g_n(x))\to 1\neq f(g(x))$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir.

Comment: Ram Murthy,  here $f$ is discontinuous sir but in the given question $f$ should be continuous.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Now the limiting functions are both $0$.

Comment: Ram Murthy, yes sir this will work for the above. Thanks for your continuous support through this platform.

Comment: @Rahul Maurya Please watch the above answer, I think you will understand it easily.

Comment: sir, what can we say about this- Let $ \lbrace f_n\rbrace$ and $\lbrace g_n\rbrace $ be two sequences of real-valued continuous functions on compact subset of R such that they converge point wise to $f$ and $g$ respectively, where $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions on R. Then what can we say about the composite function $f_n \circ g_n$. Can we say that it will converge to f∘g?

Comment: @MANISHANKARPANDEY $f_n\circ g_n$ has to be defined for the question to make sense.

Comment: Suppose it is defined then what we can say, actually Sir I am working on a problem of functional analysis and got stuck at this point.

Answer (score -1):

Let $\lbrace f_n\rbrace$ and $\lbrace g_n\rbrace $ be two sequences of real-valued continuous functions on compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that they converge pointwise to $f$ and $g$ respectively, where $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Then what can we say about the composite function $f_n \circ g_n$. Can we say that it will converge to $f\circ g$?

Comment: Why are you asking a question here?